# Appropriate definition of API interface using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a JSON in this link https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/59121517_baking/baking.json . I wish to generate a list of MyPojo class; this class contains array of ingredients, array of steps, strings like Id, names, serving and others using Retrofit 2. Kindly assist define the api interface for use in Retrofit 2.
Below is the POJO class I defined.
POJO class looks like below:

```
public class MyPojo{
private Ingredients[] ingredients;

private String id;

private String servings;

private String name;

private String image;

private Steps[] steps;

public Ingredients[] getIngredients ()
{
    return ingredients;
}

public void setIngredients (Ingredients[] ingredients)
{
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
}

public String getId ()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId (String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getServings ()
{
    return servings;
}

public void setServings (String servings)
{
    this.servings = servings;
}

public String getName ()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName (String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImage ()
{
    return image;
}

public void setImage (String image)
{
    this.image = image;
}

public Steps[] getSteps ()
{
    return steps;
}

public void setSteps (Steps[] steps)
{
    this.steps = steps;
}
```

The issue I am having now is how to get the list of the POJO class, I am defining it as:

```
   public interface getList {  
    @GET("baking.json")
    Call<List<MyPojo>> parseJsonToObject(
    );
}
```

This is not giving me the object that I want, I think I am getting it wrong where I put `Call<List<MyPojo>> parseJsonToObject()` in the interface.
Kindly assist.

Below is my Ingredients class:

```
   public class Ingredients{
private String measure;

private String ingredient;

private String quantity;

public String getMeasure ()
{
    return measure;
}

public void setMeasure (String measure)
{
    this.measure = measure;
}

public String getIngredient ()
{
    return ingredient;
}

public void setIngredient (String ingredient)
{
    this.ingredient = ingredient;
}

public String getQuantity ()
{
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity (String quantity)
{
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [measure = "+measure+", ingredient = "+ingredient+", quantity = "+quantity+"]";
}
}
```

The Step class:

```
public class Steps{
private String id;

private String shortDescription;

private String description;

private String videoURL;

private String thumbnailURL;

public String getId ()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId (String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getShortDescription ()
{
    return shortDescription;
}

public void setShortDescription (String shortDescription)
{
    this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
}

public String getDescription ()
{
    return description;
}

public void setDescription (String description)
{
    this.description = description;
}

public String getVideoURL ()
{
    return videoURL;
}

public void setVideoURL (String videoURL)
{
    this.videoURL = videoURL;
}

public String getThumbnailURL ()
{
    return thumbnailURL;
}

public void setThumbnailURL (String thumbnailURL)
{
    this.thumbnailURL = thumbnailURL;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [id = "+id+", shortDescription = "+shortDescription+", description = "+description+", videoURL = "+videoURL+", thumbnailURL = "+thumbnailURL+"]";
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show `Ingredients` and `Steps` class?

Comment: Ingredients and Steps classes have been added

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found out an answer that works for. My interface class is corrected as:

```
public interface getList {  
@GET("baking.json")
Call<ArrayList<MyPojo>> parseJsonToObject(
);
}
```

And in MyPojo class: I changed the following;

```
private List<Ingredients> ingredients = null;
private List<Steps> steps = null;
```

It is working. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Retrofit turns your HTTP API into a Java interface.

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("users/{user}/repos")
  Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

The **Retrofit** class generates an implementation of the **GitHubService** interface.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
    .build();
GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
```

Each **Call** from the created **GitHubService** can make a synchronous or asynchronous HTTP request to the remote webserver.

```
Call<List<Repo>> repos = service.listRepos("octocat");
```

source : https://square.github.io/retrofit/